# Magento : There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento, nginx

When I request to open magento CMS, there appears an error message.
Like,

### There has been an error processing your request

*Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number:* *875027730743*

I am using magento 1.8.1.0 in Ubuntu 13.10 with nginx (for HTTP Load Balancing).

How do I survive with this error? I have found several solutions, But none of those are working. Ex. [here](http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/exception-printing-disabled-default-security-reasons-error-log-record-numb-11362/#.U1DeIVa-yrR), This might be helpful. but I dont understand where I do create 'tmp'?

Comment: for ,printing the error ,goto your magento dir>errors> find local.xml.sample rename to local.xml and see the error

Comment: Thanks, I already have tried it but it didint work. It occurred some mysql connection error.

Comment: Change back afterwards so you don't create a hackable website by publicly creating a GoogleDorkable error page that spills your stack traces out where everyone can see them. There is a reason why Magento stopped doing that and writes the error message as a file with the log number as its name in `var/report/`. Using FTP to access the error report files isn't that much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Problem happened for mysql service error. Magento coudnt connect with mysql. But I didnt get what the error is it? There may be some other error tracking technique for magento. But the easy way to get the error, just rename the local.xml.sample (you may find it in (dir)/errors/) to local.xml (solution given by Amit). If error seems like

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Trace:

```
#0 /var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /var/www/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /var/www/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Just check the service status

```
~# service mysql status
```

If it shows

```
mysql stop/waiting
```

Just start it

```
~# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

I hope problem is sloved!

***feel free to edit if need any correction***